# Compass and Sass compile times really slow using Grunt watch - 25 seconds for small files

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, compass

I am fairly new to Grunt, Compass and Sass. Whenever I make a change to a `.scss` file it takes nearly 25s to run the task. I must be doing something wrong. This is my setup:

I have my `scss` partials like so:

`_buttons.scss, _colors.scss, _typography.scss` and so on. These are imported by a `_base.scss` file. This in turn is imported into my `main.scss` file along with `compass`.

My `gruntfile` looks like this:

```
module.exports = function( grunt ){     
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');        

    grunt.initConfig({
        //UGLIFY
        uglify:{
            options: {
                beautify:true   
            },//options
            my_target: {
                files:{
                    'js/main.js': ['_/js/partials/*.js']
                }//files
            }//my target
        },//uglify

        //COMPASS
        compass: {
            dev:{
                options: {
                    config: 'config.rb'
                }//options
            }//development mode
        },//compass

        //WATCH
        watch:{
            options: {
                livereload:true,
                spawn: false
            },
            scripts: {  
                files: ['_/js/partials/*.js'],
                tasks:['uglify']
            },//scripts
            sass: {
                files: ['_/sass/**/*.scss'], 
                tasks: ['compass:dev']
            },//sass
            html: {
                files: ['*.html']
            },//html
        }//watch
    }),//init config
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'watch')
}//exports
```

Other questions I've read suggested setting `spawn` to false (which I thought it was by default anyway) but this has made no difference. The uglify task takes only a second or two. So what is going wrong with my sass files?

**UPDATE**

If I run `grunt -verbose` this is the output:

[image]

It looks like Grunt is watching every single file, not just the ones I have specified. i.e. the php directory.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems that the example `grunt-contrib-compass` config is quite different to yours: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#watch Worth a try?

Comment: @TonyBarnes good point however I gave it a try and it made no difference. My compass task points to a congif.rb file which has the same info.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should checkout to the grunt-sass ( it is c++ library for compiling sass https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sass) and spritesmith (https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-spritesmith) for generating sprites

I have the same problem, when I use compass on a small project, it takes 3s for compiling styles and another 7s for generaating sprites.

Comment: Sadly compass is necessary for what I am working on.

Comment: But you are dead right about compass being slow and grunt-sass much faster: 25s or more for compass, .05s for grunt-sass. Insane.